# Are goniometric functions only defined for oriented angles?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

My textbook defines sine and cosine functions of only oriented angles. For example cosine of an oriented angle is the signed abscissa / the radius of the circle.
I've got two questions:

1. Every time we meet the cosine of an angle, are we implicitly meaning that this angle is an oriented one, even if not specified? (i.e. the clockwise or counterclockwise sense matter even if we don't care)?
2. When we talk about law of cosines, (i.e. c = sqrt( a^2 + b^2- 2*a*b*cosC)), the cosC is meant to be a cosine of an oriented angle C, even though orientation doesn't really matter?

They may sound odd questions, but they are not in physics context, where sign of angles matter and textbook basic definition are not so clear about that.

Comment: In pure mathematics, the trigonometric functions are functions of numbers, not angles. You might let the input number be the length of a directed arc along the unit circle in order to define the functions, but it's still really just a number. It's the application of a trig function to a geometric figure that determines how the angle is measured and converted to the correct number for input to the function.

Comment: @DavidK  Thank you for your answer. Yes, i know that arguments of real trig functions are just real numbers. I was stuck specifically in application of the trig fuctions to circles, and wondering: if any argument of a real trig function is a number (positive, null and negative) and it can represent an angle of a circle, does that mean that all angles that i can represent are meant to be oriented (because they are measured with sign)? And this even though the specific orientation is not explicitly mentioned, isn't it?

Comment: Non-oriented angles have sizes between $0$ and $\pi$ (in radians). Never any higher or lower. Oriented angles can have any numerical value. Defining trig functions using oriented angles is just a way of extending them beyond the $0 - \pi$ range. For an unoriented angle $\theta$, there is no recognizable sense in having $\sin \theta < 0$. The very idea of declaring the distance represented by $\sin \theta$ is negative is the same as choosing an orientation for the angle.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your answer. But this implies that there is no difference between a non oriented angle and a positively oriented angle, right? They have the same measure so it doesn't realy matter the orientation, is it?

Comment: As far as trig functions go, there isn't. Draw the unit circle about the angle vertex. From the intersection with one side of the angle drop a perpendicular to the other. The length of the perpendicular is the sine of the angle. It doesn't matter which side you choose, both perpendiculars are the same length. Similarly for cosine. "Oriented angles" is just a trick for extending trig functions from $[0,\pi]$ to all of $\Bbb R$. The sign and cosine for an oriented angle are the same as for the corresponding unoriented angle, except that the sine might be negated.